# Calculating Pin Placement for Self-Image Formation in a Concave Mirror with Liquid Fill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

The question is as follows:

Figure shows a concave mirror of focal length F with its principal axis vertical. In mirror a transparent liquid of refractive index μ is filled upto height d. Find where on axis of mirror a pin should be placed so that its image will be formed on itself

[image]

Now the answer is very simple if we consider the object to placed such that it appears on the radius of curvature of the mirror after refraction.

Why can't we place the object in the liquid such that after refraction it **appears** to be present at the object itself when viewed from outside?

In this case light ray OD upon reflection follows path DE and gets refracted  as shown, when retraced OE gives image position at the same point, O.
[image]